# icons are showing in full black color in android drawer bar do you know how to fix it?

Tags: java, android, mobile

icons are not showing in activity main drawer they are just showing like full black i dont know why can anyone help me? here is my xml code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WLIc.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using `.png` files which are not supported by navigation drawer. It only works with `.svg` or `Android Vector Asset`.

If you want to use these pictures, you need to convert them to `.svg` file from [here](https://www.pngtosvg.com).

### How to convert ?

1. Scroll down and you will something like this -> [image]
2. Click on `Choose a file` and pick the image you want.
3. Once you select, you will see this below it -> [image](I have used my image)
4. Click on the `Generate` button and wait for a while-> [image]
5. Once you see an image in the side, you know that it has been converted -> [image]
6. Click on the `Download SVG` button and you will find it in your file explorer.

Once you download them, you can add it to the drawable folder. But make sure that you delete the previous png files.

Tada! Its done! You them in the navigation drawer and you get the icons too!